# Read User Wall Post and others who posted on wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am new to the facebook graph API ,but I know the basics. Now I need help from you all about how to read user wall posts and others who posted on the wall of any user, with `read_stream`. But I don't know how to call it. I tried some way but I was able to read just the name and basic info. I need help in reading objects. Please help me!!!

```
<?php
define('FACEBOOK_APP_ID', 'xxxxxx');
define('FACEBOOK_SECRET', 'xxxxxx');
function get_facebook_cookie($app_id, $application_secret) {
$args = array();
parse_str(trim($_COOKIE['fbs_' . $app_id], '\\"'), $args);
ksort($args);
$payload = '';
foreach ($args as $key => $value) {
if ($key != 'sig') {
  $payload .= $key . '=' . $value;
 }
 }
  if (md5($payload . $application_secret) != $args['sig']) {
   return null;
  }
 return $args;
  }
  $cookie = get_facebook_cookie(FACEBOOK_APP_ID, FACEBOOK_SECRET);
   ?>
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
         xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
   <body>
   <?php
   echo 'Your Facebook ID: '.$cookie;
    if ($cookie) {
   //cookie is set, user is logged in
   $user = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/'.$cookie['uid']));
   //Display the facebook user ID, name, gender and Facebook URL in the web browser
   echo '<br />';
   echo 'Your Facebook ID: '.$user->{'id'};
   echo '<br />';
   echo 'Your name: '.$user->{'name'};
   echo '<br />';
   echo 'Your gender: '.$user->{'gender'};
   echo '<br />';
   echo 'Your Facebook URL: '.$user->{'link'};
   echo '<br />';
   echo '<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/'.$user->{'id.'/picture"                      alt="'.$user->       {'name'}.'"/>';
   echo '<br />';
   echo '<fb:login-button autologoutlink="true"></fb:login-button>';
   }
   else
   {
   //user is not logged in, display the Facebook login button
          echo '<h2>Facebook Application Test page</h2>';
   echo '<br />';
   echo' message somethng';
   </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you must take permission from your users

```
    $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?"
    ."client_id=".$app_id."&"
    ."redirect_uri=http://apps.facebook.com/".$app_name."/&scope=read_stream";

    <script language="javascript">window.open('<?php echo $url ?>', '_parent', '');</script>
```

Then you can get user's wall. There is an example here.

```
    if(isset($_GET["code"])){
        if(isset($_REQUEST['state']) == isset($_SESSION['state'])) {
            $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
                         . "client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . "http://apps.facebook.com/".$app_name."/"
                         . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret . "&code=" . $_GET["code"];
            $response = @file_get_contents($token_url);
            $params = null;
            parse_str($response, $params);
            $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$user_id."/feed/?access_token=".$params['access_token'];
            $user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));
            foreach($user as $feeds)
            {
                foreach($feeds as $feed)
                {
                    if(isset($feed->link))
                    {
                        echo $feed->link."<br>";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but now this two errors popping out:
                        
Warning: file_get_contents(http://graph.facebook.com//feed/?access_token=) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error in /data/multiserv/users/491819/projects/1209278/www/fb/abc.php on line 34
                                               
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /data/multiserv/users/491819/projects/1209278/www/fb/abc.php on line 35

Comment: What is your php version? You need PHP5.2+ to use the Facebook SDK

Comment: And change allow_url_fopen = on in your php.ini file

Comment: thnks for ur fast reply.. and am using subdomain free hosting site. am not able to edit php.ini . any other wway to do it sir?

Comment: is PHP SDK require for this, we cannot bypass sir?

Comment: You can use ini_set function to change php.ini settings in your file.

Comment: how sir? any suggestion or tutorial?

Comment: just write that top of your php file

ini_set("allow_url_fopen","on");

Comment: thnks for the help. i will try it.. and in above code which first you have answered, no need of PHP require() na?

Comment: you need PHP5.2+ then change your php.ini settings with text editing or using ini_set function